# What approach to use for parsing a file with fixed length records, when the record layout isn't known until runtime?

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, file-io

I want to parse a file based on a record layout provided in another file.

Basically there will be a definition file, which is a comma delimited list of fields and their respective lengths. There will be many of these, a new one will be loaded each time I run the program.

```
firstName,text,20
middleInitial,text,1
lastName,text,20
salary,number,10
```

Then I will display a blank table with the supplied column headings, and an option to add data by clicking a button or whatever - I haven't decided yet.

I also want to have an option to both load data from a file, or save data to a file, with the file matching the format described in the definition file.

For example, a file to load (or one produced by the save function) for the above definition file might look like this.

```
Adam                DSmith               50000
Brent               GWilliams            45000
Harry               TThompson            47500
```

What kind of patterns could be useful here, and can anyone give me pointers of a rough guide on how to structure the way data is internally stored and modeled.

I would like to think I can find my way around the java documentation alright, but if anyone can point me at somewhere to start looking, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: do you have any control over the format (definition) of these files? From your example, am I to understand there is a predefined max length for each field, with the remainder filled in with whitespace? Why aren't they comma- or tab-delimited as is usual with flat/csv files?

Comment: Yes I have full control over the definition files, but they are generated based on the datasource which has fixed length fields and the import/export methods for that system only support fixed width file formats, not delimited formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like to me that you have a howToParse file and infoToParse file with the directions of how to parse information and the information to parse in these files respectively.

First, I would read in the howToParse file and create some sort of dynamic Parser object.  It looks like each line in this file is a different ParsingStep object.  Then you just need to read the line which will be stored as a String object and just split the ParsingStep into its 3 parts: field name, type of data, length of data.

```
// Create new parser to hold parsing steps.
Parser dynamicParser = new Parser();

// Create new scanner to read through parse file.
Scanner parseFileScanner = new Scanner(howToParseFileName);

// *** Add exception handling as necessary *** this is just an example    

// Read till end of file.
while (parseFileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = parseFileScanner.nextLine(); // Get next line in file.

    String[] lineSplit = line.split(","); // Split on comma
    String fieldName   = lineSplit[0];
    String dataType    = lineSplit[1];
    String dataLength  = lineSplit[2];  // Convert to Integer with Integer.parseInt();

    ParsingStep step = new ParsingStep(fieldName, dataType, dataLength);
    dynamicParser.addStep(step);
}

parseFileScanner.close();
```

Then you would have how to parse a line, then you just need to parse through the other file and store the information from that file, probably in an array.

```
// Open infoToParse file and start reading.
Scanner infoScanner = new Scanner(infoToParseFileName);

// Add exception handling.
while (infoScanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = infoScanner.nextLine();

    // Parse line and return a Person object or maybe just a Map of field names to values
    Map<String,String> personMap = dynamicParser.parse(line);
} 

infoScanner.close();
```

Then the only other code is just making sure the parser is parsing in the correct order.

```
public class Parser {
    private ArrayList<ParsingStep> steps;

    public Parser() {
        steps = new ArrayList<ParsingStep>();
    }

    public void addStep(ParsingStep step) {
        steps.add(step);
    }

    public Map<String,String> parse(String line) {
        String remainingLine = line;

        for (ParsingStep step : steps) {
            remainingLine = step.parse(remainingLine);
        }

        return map; // Somehow convert to map.
    }
}
```

Personally, I would add some error checking in the parse steps just in case the infoToParse file is not in the proper format.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thats exactly what I needed. That will help me break it down into much more manageable chunks of work. Cheers!